# Substructural skepticism

Tags: logic, skepticism

The SEP article on [substructural logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-substructural/#2) mentions an issue of repeated premises:

> So, I might have *X*, *X* ⊢ *A*, which says that I can use *X* twice to get *A*. I might not have *X* ⊢ *A*, which says that I can use *X* once alone to get *A*. ... There are other formal logics in which the *contraction rule* (from *X*, *X* ⊢ *A* to *X* ⊢ *A*) is absent.

Now, I spend a decent (or maybe inordinate) amount of time elsewhere online, analyzing a conspiracy-theory cult whose members claim that various people are unwilling to debate them properly, but which members seem to think that debating means asking the same question over and over again and only accepting answers that they (the members) are already inclined to accept (when they accept any answers, that is, since otherwise these members seem willing to mutate their narrative in the wildest ways, whatever comes their way with respect to the facts). So I was thinking over whether this cult's thought processes involve a sort of postulate in erotetic repeated-premise logic, where the cult's members tend to think that premises do need to be repeated a lot for some inefficient reason, and where questions, when used as implicit premises, then have to be asked over and over again.

Then I abstracted over the issue of that cult and just wondered if the conspiracy-theory mindset, or even some forms of more general skepticism, work(s) off this kind of basis. I thought I had seen somewhere that premise-repetition/copying could be framed in terms of multiset theory, and since some [multigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph#) are multiset-theoretic, then modulo epistemic graph theory, maybe we could represent some form of general skepticism along these lines. I suppose maybe it would be clearer to go to erotetic graphs first (and define epistemic graphs as an assertoric subclass of erotetic graphs overall), then.

**Is there a kind of skepticism, as a reluctance to accept various questions as settled, that can be identified with a willingness to copy premises indefinitely, to extend *X*, *X*, ... ⊢ *A* without the intention to stop extending it?** I wouldn't necessarily want to say that this would illustrate how this form of skepticism is irrational/unjustified, although maybe if these kinds of skeptics were confronted with the substructure of their own attitude, their obstinacy might be undermined by mental exhaustion (they would realize that they were exhausting themselves by inefficiently copying their questions/premises so much).

---

Cambridge University Press has a page for an essay ["Substructural Inquisitive Logics"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/review-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/substructural-inquisitive-logics/81285524FFC11723B452B2D8434FEF79) that might be pertinent, though I don't have CUP access so I can't check. I'm going to look through a presentation on [substructural proof theory](https://shawn-standefer.github.io/pdfs/nassli2018-pt-lpa-2-substructural-logics.pdf) to see if they address something like the above, also.

Comment: I'm not precisely following your "identification" in that penultimate paragraph. Are you saying the skeptics insist on copying premises indefinitely, and would no longer be skeptical if shown that can't always be done? Or are you saying vice versa (can't decide whether that would be converse or inverse:)? If you're saying what I think, read about Girard's linear logic (resource-aware logic) vending machine example. That should convince anybody. By the way, re your last paragraph, just see http://libgen.rs/scimag/?q=VIT+PUNCOCHAR for that CUP article.

Comment: @JohnForkosh from what I looked over, linear logic has something to do with "resources," so it's less that stubbornly asking questions regardless of resolution, or delaying acceptance of premises, are impossible, more that they're a waste of "resources."

Comment: Not a "waste", per se. It's that the proof process *X|-A* necessarily "uses up" (called "discharges") the premise=resource. Anyway, still not precisely sure about which logical rule(s) of inference you're saying is(are) bothering your skeptics. Maybe what I'm saying is completely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @JohnForkosh if I take the extreme conspiracy theorists as representative samples of this sort of skepticism, well, usually we at the subreddit where we monitor them will accuse them of loose things like "psychological projection" or "bad faith," but I have persistently thought that some kind of "anti-logic" is at play. Or, a lower-order logic somehow indexed by a negative number, if that's possible. For example, those "theorists" whine about "dangerous vaccines" constantly, no matter how much their paranoia is negated by the evidence, claiming that people who disagree "won't debate with us."

Comment: Maybe this is more of psychological/sociological issue, then, less than philosophy, but I also wanted to know if we could expand on the themes of epistemic graph theory to describe new solutions (or absences of solutions) to epistemic regress problems.

Comment: I hope you don't end up making them *more* efficient. But if you came up with a thought which would correct their mental functioning, that would be great. A sort of mind vaccine... Spread from person to person.